# Form add new data in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

```
 This is the database structure
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
| u_userid | u_username | u_password | u_rolecode | datacontractului | salariulunar | zileconcediu | salariuavans | datorie |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|     1    |   highmob  |  password  | SUPERADMIN |                  |              |              |              |         |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
|     2    |   angajat  |   parola   |    ADMIN   |                  |              |              |              |         |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

I have this form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id=userid1>
    <p>
        <label for="datacontractului">Data Contractului:</label>
        <input type="text" name="datacontractului" id="datacontractului">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="salariulunar">Salariu Lunar:</label>
        <input type="text" name="salariulunar" id="salariulunar">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="zileconcediu">Zile de concediu luate:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zileconcediu" id="zileconcediu">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="salariuavans">Salariu in avans:</label>
        <input type="text" name="salariuavans" id="salariuavans">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="datorie">Datorie:</label>
        <input type="text" name="datorie" id="datorie">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Next form for u_userid2:

```
<form action="" method="post" id=userid2>
    <p>
        <label for="datacontractului">Data Contractului:</label>
        <input type="text" name="datacontractului" id="datacontractului">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="salariulunar">Salariu Lunar:</label>
        <input type="text" name="salariulunar" id="salariulunar">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="zileconcediu">Zile de concediu luate:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zileconcediu" id="zileconcediu">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="salariuavans">Salariu in avans:</label>
        <input type="text" name="salariuavans" id="salariuavans">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="datorie">Datorie:</label>
        <input type="text" name="datorie" id="datorie">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need the form to insert each input in specific table column for specific user in the same page.

I hope you guys understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button name in first form 
value=btnfirst 
then check if the button is pressed or not
if (isset($_POST['btn_first'])){
    get all the values here
and write the insert query

}

Comment: even if i change that it wont post in database :(